# Facebook registration process for Android App

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I am in the process of registering my android app in facebook. I am following the steps shown in the document
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

This needs the package name and the class name. I am aware of the package name. Could you please let me know what is "class name". Is this the launcher Activity (MainActivity.class) ?

[image]

Comment: try this com.example.appname.MainActivity

Comment: you mean the actual package name followed by MainActivity ?  <packagename>.MainActivity